# Modulus of continuity an exponential type function

Tags: real-analysis

Fixed $0<a<1$, define $f(x):=(1-x)^{a}$ for every $x\in [0,1]$. Recalling that the modulus of continuity of $f$ of order $\varepsilon$ is given by
$\omega(f,\varepsilon):=\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|:|x-y|\leq \varepsilon\}$, How can I find an upper bound for this function $f(x)$?

Thanks in advance for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact upper bound on the decreasing function $f$ is $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} f(x)=f(0)=1$. The exact value of $\omega(f,\varepsilon)$ for $\varepsilon>0$ is $f(1-1\wedge\varepsilon)-f(1)=1\wedge\varepsilon^a$, because $f$ is decreasing and concave.

Comment: Very thanks for your answer! Then, the value of the modulus of continuity, in this case, is due to "f is decreasing and concave"?

Comment: Since $f$ is decreasing and concave, it is indeed easy to find the simple expression for the modulus of continuity of continuity.